# could not run the authentication on android

Tags: android, httprequest

I have a java project which allow me get an access token to connect to the AirVantage Cloud, i wanted to use the method of authentication in an android application but it didn't work.

```
MainActivity.java

public void sendMessage(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityLogged.class);
    /*EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      login = editText1.getText().toString();
     password = editText2.getText().toString();*/
            Log.i("aaaaaaaaaaaaa","je suis on sendmessage");
            login="my_login";
            password="my_password";

            try {
                Log.i("gggggggggg","je suis dans try");
                access_token = Request
                        .Get(apiUrl + "/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username="
                                + login + "&password=" + password + "&client_id="
                                + apiKey + "&client_secret=" + apiSecret).execute()
                        .handleResponse(new ResponseHandler<String>() {

                            public String handleResponse(final HttpResponse response)
                                    throws IOException {
                                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() >= 300) {
                                    throw new HttpResponseException(statusLine
                                            .getStatusCode(), statusLine
                                            .getReasonPhrase());
                                }
                                if (entity == null) {
                                    Log.i("eeeeeeeeeeeeeee","dans la condition");
                                    throw new ClientProtocolException(
                                            "Response contains no content");
                                }

                                try {
                                    String content = IOUtils.toString(entity
                                            .getContent());
                                    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(content);
                                    return result.getString("access_token");
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    throw new ClientProtocolException(
                                            "Malformed JSON", e);
                                }
                            }

                        });

                System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
                System.out.println("(if you're curious it looks like this: "
                        + access_token + " )");
                System.out.println();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

//Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityLogged.class);
     intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, access_token);
       startActivity(intent);




}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/digitalClock1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="@string/log" 
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    />
```

but it show me these errors

```
04-30 10:25:13.386: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 13129:                 Lorg/apache/http/entity/ByteArrayEntity;.<init> ([BII)V
04-30 10:25:13.390: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 13162: Lorg/apache/http/entity/FileEntity;.<init> (Ljava/io/File;Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)V
04-30 10:25:13.394: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5827 (DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET) in Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HTTP;
04-30 10:25:13.394: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 12347: Lorg/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity;.<init> (Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)V
04-30 10:25:13.394: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5827 (DEF_CONTENT_CHARSET) in Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HTTP;
04-30 10:25:13.433: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 13181: Lorg/apache/http/entity/InputStreamEntity;.<init> (Ljava/io/InputStream;JLorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)V
04-30 10:25:13.433: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 13200: Lorg/apache/http/entity/StringEntity;.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)V
04-30 10:25:13.531: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve static method 15920: Lorg/apache/http/util/EntityUtils;.consume (Lorg/apache/http/HttpEntity;)V
04-30 10:25:13.539: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 13131:  Lorg/apache/http/entity/ByteArrayEntity;.<init> ([BLorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;)V
04-30 10:25:13.539: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 12920: Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/Scheme;.<init> (Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory;)V
04-30 10:25:13.566: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 12148: Lorg/apache/http/auth/AuthScope;.<init> (Lorg/apache/http/HttpHost;)V
04-30 10:25:13.566: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 13456: Lorg/apache/http/impl/auth/BasicScheme;.<init> (Lorg/apache/http/auth/ChallengeState;)V
04-30 10:25:13.566: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 13456:  Lorg/apache/http/impl/auth/BasicScheme;.<init> (Lorg/apache/http/auth/ChallengeState;)V
04-30 10:25:13.570: W/dalvikvm(7636): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 12512: Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase;.reset ()V
04-30 10:25:13.574: W/dalvikvm(7636): Exception Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/http/client/fluent/Executor;
04-30 10:25:13.574: W/dalvikvm(7636): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40caf300)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     ... 11 more
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.execute(Request.java:145)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at com.OXIA.sitep.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:64)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     ... 14 more
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.<init>
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     at org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor.<clinit>(Executor.java:75)
04-30 10:25:13.597: E/AndroidRuntime(7636):     ... 16 more
```

can anyone help me. thank you in advance